# Close all opened Windows by ONE CMD Command

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, powershell

I would like to close all opened windows (from programs, windows explorer, etc...) by using CMD. The easiest way I found is not using CMD but running these two powershell commands:

```
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}

Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | stop-process
```

Which works pretty well, but I don't know how to execute them right from CMD.
I tried the commands below using `powershell -noexit` to execute powershell commands and `^` to ignore some cmd functions, but it does not work:

```
powershell -noexit "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application^).Windows(^) ^| foreach-object {$_.quit(^)}"

powershell -noexit "Get-Process ^| Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} ^| stop-process"
```

And I do not want to use `taskkill` command or create a .ps1 file and execute it by using `start .ps1` either.

Comment: `powershell -command "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\"} | stop-process"`

Comment: It sounds like you want to type this manually each time. You could reduce this Powershell by using aliases. For example, `Where-Object` becomes `?`.

Comment: Oh, it's so easy, thank you so much! That's right what I wanted :)

Comment: Note that `Stop-Process` will actually end the entire process, which can include multiple windows and any background component. Also this is somewhat dangerous in that it can leave any open files in a bad state. You're better off [gracefully closing the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436916/gracefully-closing-a-process-in-a-remote-session) where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by [PetSerAl](https://superuser.com/users/364455/petseral).

```
powershell -command "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\"} | stop-process"
```

**Note that `Stop-Process` will actually end the entire process.**